# Why do my quadratic forecasts look so weird?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm new to time series analysis in R and am having some trouble getting forecasts from a particular time series set and model I've built.

This is my time series data, it's 144 days of the asx200 closing price, but my classmates and I were never given the start and end dates, so I've defined the ts object as below

```
dataTS <- ts(data$`Closing Price`, frequency=255)
dataTS
```

```
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(1, 144) 
Frequency = 255 
  [1] 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 81.38536 79.83485 79.93370 80.23789 81.33359 81.14499 79.80375 79.43928 81.41525

 [19] 80.70474 79.69196 81.87581 83.51553 82.56475 80.87173 80.72899 83.64094 84.88065 82.33275 84.32522 84.89717 83.40710 81.37416 80.95209 82.92598 83.99487 81.82895

 [37] 84.99273 85.50362 83.98170 81.17617 81.80690 86.13822 87.06587 83.57672 86.29252 85.58256 83.77695 80.39828 82.20623 88.28351 89.03392 85.63961 87.10639 84.92215

 [55] 82.17131 80.00454 81.63989 87.61051 87.22371 84.96421 88.55203 87.53684 84.11937 82.27707 83.09376 87.79680 88.11651 85.91388 89.92467 88.68123 84.58792 83.52971

 [73] 85.20692 90.62572 91.49070 90.07306 95.31403 93.25239 86.41805 83.94959 87.10673 93.23133 92.43702 90.80849 95.48193 91.64825 82.60358 78.17113 81.01983 86.86542

 [91] 86.53665 85.42238 90.39699 86.85428 78.12587 74.29434 78.62797 84.89108 83.41155 80.45274 84.53619 80.45623 71.39215 66.56142 71.14703 75.80771 74.22025 72.14369

[109] 76.89173 71.38474 61.95091 57.37281 63.16960 67.80788 65.79209 63.46010 69.09905 63.59795 53.19971 49.52717 56.96862 60.89146 59.20133 58.66473 65.12076 58.77136

[127] 47.24968 44.21060 50.65772 52.97805 50.63288 50.26958 56.19423 48.64413 35.37176 30.81471 36.18630 38.41415 35.68011 34.78598 40.24962 33.00511 20.00861 15.46719
```

Following this, I've built this quadratic model:

```
t = time(dataTS)
t2 = t^2
model2 = lm(dataTS ~ t + t2)
summary(model2)
```

The model showed a good R^2 etc., so I want to do a forecast.

I've used the code below for the forecast:

```
h <- 5
t <- time(dataTS)
t2 <- t^2
aheadTimes <- data.frame(t= seq(1, 144+h, 1),
                         t2 = seq(1, 144+h, 1)^2)
frcModel2 <- predict(model2, newdata= aheadTimes, interval = 'prediction')

frcModel2
```

And this code below to plot it:

```
plot(dataTS, xlim=c(1,2), ylab="ASX200 Closing Price Series", main = "Forecasts from the quadratic model fitted to the ASX200 Closing Price Series")
lines(ts(as.vector(frcModel2[,3]), start = 1.59), col="blue", type="l")
lines(ts(as.vector(frcModel2[,1]), start = 1.59), col = "red", type="l")
lines(ts(as.vector(frcModel2[,2]), start = 1.59), col = "blue", type="l")

legend("topleft", lty=1, pch=1, col=c("black","blue","red"),
       text.width = 18,
       c("Data", "5% forecast limits", "Forecast"))
```

However, the resulting plot looks super weird and I don't really understand what I've done wrong?

[image]

I'm not sure whether I've messed up the forecast itself or the plot, but I definitely know the plot doesn't look how it should.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm a little stuck!

Let me know if I need to provide any further information to help you help me :)

Comment: There is a code attempt of what you don't want but no descrioption of what you do want so I can't tell what it is but if you want to plot the data plus a point 5 deltat units into the future with prediction bounds then `t <- time(dataTS);
model2 <- lm(dataTS ~ t + I(t^2));
rng <- range(t);
tpred <- rng[2] + 5 * deltat(t);
pred <- predict(model2, list(t = tpred), interval = "prediction");
plot(dataTS, xlim = c(rng[1], tpred));
segments(x0 = tpred, y0 = pred[1, "lwr"], 
x1 = tpred, y1 = pred[1, "upr"], lty = 2);
points(tpred, pred[1, "fit"], pch = 20)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you chose frequency of 255, I think it should be just 1 for 1 day.

```
dataTS <- ts(dat$closing_price, frequency=1)
dataTS
# Time Series:
#   Start = 1 
# End = 144 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 80.00000 81.38536 79.83485
# [12] 79.93370 80.23789 81.33359 81.14499 79.80375 79.43928 81.41525 80.70474 79.69196 81.87581 83.51553
# [23] 82.56475 80.87173 80.72899 83.64094 84.88065 82.33275 84.32522 84.89717 83.40710 81.37416 80.95209
# [34] 82.92598 83.99487 81.82895 84.99273 85.50362 83.98170 81.17617 81.80690 86.13822 87.06587 83.57672
# [45] 86.29252 85.58256 83.77695 80.39828 82.20623 88.28351 89.03392 85.63961 87.10639 84.92215 82.17131
# [56] 80.00454 81.63989 87.61051 87.22371 84.96421 88.55203 87.53684 84.11937 82.27707 83.09376 87.79680
# [67] 88.11651 85.91388 89.92467 88.68123 84.58792 83.52971 85.20692 90.62572 91.49070 90.07306 95.31403
# [78] 93.25239 86.41805 83.94959 87.10673 93.23133 92.43702 90.80849 95.48193 91.64825 82.60358 78.17113
# [89] 81.01983 86.86542 86.53665 85.42238 90.39699 86.85428 78.12587 74.29434 78.62797 84.89108 83.41155
# [100] 80.45274 84.53619 80.45623 71.39215 66.56142 71.14703 75.80771 74.22025 72.14369 76.89173 71.38474
# [111] 61.95091 57.37281 63.16960 67.80788 65.79209 63.46010 69.09905 63.59795 53.19971 49.52717 56.96862
# [122] 60.89146 59.20133 58.66473 65.12076 58.77136 47.24968 44.21060 50.65772 52.97805 50.63288 50.26958
# [133] 56.19423 48.64413 35.37176 30.81471 36.18630 38.41415 35.68011 34.78598 40.24962 33.00511 20.00861
# [144] 15.46719
```

For the model, even third is significant and *R<sup>2</sup>* is even better.

```
tm <- time(dataTS)
model2 <- lm(dataTS ~ poly(tm, 3, raw=TRUE))
summary(model2)$coe |> round(3)
#                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)                80.194      1.479  54.220    0.000
# poly(tm, 3, raw = TRUE)1   -0.074      0.088  -0.838    0.404
# poly(tm, 3, raw = TRUE)2    0.007      0.001   4.962    0.000
# poly(tm, 3, raw = TRUE)3    0.000      0.000  -9.981    0.000
```

For the ahead times you want to start prediction at the nest day, i.e. `max(tm) + 1`

```
h <- 5
aheadTimes <- seq.int(max(tm) + 1, by=1, length.out=h)
pred <- as.data.frame(predict(model2, newdata=list(tm=aheadTimes),
                              interval='prediction'))
```

To close the gap in the plot, we could `rbind` the last known value, for both the prediction and the confidence bounds.

```
pred <- rbind(dataTS[length(dataTS)], pred)  ## rbind value of last cosing day
```

For plotting the prediction lines we may use `matlines`, where `aheadTimes` needs `max(tm)` as first value to match up with the altered `pred` data.

```
plot(dataTS, xlim=c(0, max(aheadTimes)), ylim=range(c(pred, dataTS)))
matlines(c(max(tm), aheadTimes), pred, col=4, lty=c(1, 2, 2))
```

[image]

This looks a little better, however polynomial prediction might not be the best method to predict time series, where usually ARIMA models are applied. For a quick data driven prediction w/o covariates you could use `forecast::auto.arima`.

```
forecast::forecast(dataTS, h=5, level=95, model=forecast::auto.arima(dataTS)) |>
  plot()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(closing_price = c(80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 81.38536, 79.83485, 79.9337, 80.23789, 81.33359, 81.14499, 
79.80375, 79.43928, 81.41525, 80.70474, 79.69196, 81.87581, 83.51553, 
82.56475, 80.87173, 80.72899, 83.64094, 84.88065, 82.33275, 84.32522, 
84.89717, 83.4071, 81.37416, 80.95209, 82.92598, 83.99487, 81.82895, 
84.99273, 85.50362, 83.9817, 81.17617, 81.8069, 86.13822, 87.06587, 
83.57672, 86.29252, 85.58256, 83.77695, 80.39828, 82.20623, 88.28351, 
89.03392, 85.63961, 87.10639, 84.92215, 82.17131, 80.00454, 81.63989, 
87.61051, 87.22371, 84.96421, 88.55203, 87.53684, 84.11937, 82.27707, 
83.09376, 87.7968, 88.11651, 85.91388, 89.92467, 88.68123, 84.58792, 
83.52971, 85.20692, 90.62572, 91.4907, 90.07306, 95.31403, 93.25239, 
86.41805, 83.94959, 87.10673, 93.23133, 92.43702, 90.80849, 95.48193, 
91.64825, 82.60358, 78.17113, 81.01983, 86.86542, 86.53665, 85.42238, 
90.39699, 86.85428, 78.12587, 74.29434, 78.62797, 84.89108, 83.41155, 
80.45274, 84.53619, 80.45623, 71.39215, 66.56142, 71.14703, 75.80771, 
74.22025, 72.14369, 76.89173, 71.38474, 61.95091, 57.37281, 63.1696, 
67.80788, 65.79209, 63.4601, 69.09905, 63.59795, 53.19971, 49.52717, 
56.96862, 60.89146, 59.20133, 58.66473, 65.12076, 58.77136, 47.24968, 
44.2106, 50.65772, 52.97805, 50.63288, 50.26958, 56.19423, 48.64413, 
35.37176, 30.81471, 36.1863, 38.41415, 35.68011, 34.78598, 40.24962, 
33.00511, 20.00861, 15.46719)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-144L))
```